# Need to show the content with php

Tags: php, regex, curl

im using curl,im trying to show this, 'h3.a-size-large.a-text-normal' on my page.And i dont know why but it doesnt work,can someone help?Sorry if the code is wrong,im new at php.There is the code:

-PHP

```
include_once 'simple_html_dom.php';

$html = file_get_html('https://www.amazon.com/');

foreach($html->find('h3.a-size-large.a-text-normal') as $element) 
       echo $element . '<br>';

?>
```

Comment: amazon has an api, you should be using that

Comment: you say "it doesn't work"  what is happening?  What is the value of `$element`

Comment: so its not possible to take that element?

Comment: well it shows 'Try different image
Conditions of Use
Privacy Policy'